# CakePHP 2.X : SESSION Externa

Tags: php, session, cakephp-2

Eu tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho a minha aplicação rodando com o CakePHP 2.X, porém o sistema de autenticação é externo e eu não possuo acesso a ele, a única coisa que me foi passada são as variaveis $_SESSION disponibilizadas pelo servidor.

Há alguma maneira de acessar essas `$_SESSION` dentro do CakePHP? Usando as funcionalidades do Framework para conseguir os valores?

### EDIT 1

Usando o comando `session_start()`, dentro do View eu consigo recuperar os valores, porém eu necessito recuperar esses valores no Model...

### EDIT 2

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        if($_SESSION['chave']){
            $this->Session->write('chave', $_SESSION['chave']);
            $this->Session->write('nmCracha', $_SESSION['nmCracha']);
            $this->Session->write('prefDep', $_SESSION['prefDep']);

        }else{
            $this->redirect('http://...../index.html');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo necessidade de usar recursos do CakePHP pra isso, na verdade não sei se tem algum recurso nativo para isso. O que aconselho é usar o PHP puro neste caso, ou seja, trabalhando com as globais $_SESSION diretamente. Não vejo nenhum problema com isso.

Comment: Usar a Global ajuda no View e lá funciona, porém eu preciso passar para o Controller, quando tento recuperar o valor ele me retorna nulo, já de um `print_r($this->Session->read())` mais ele não encontra os valores e infelizmente não tenho acesso ao servidor de autenticação, e muito menos suporte por parte da Diretoria de Tecnologia para me ajudar...

Comment: E no View só consigo acesso utilizando `session_start()`, pelo SessionHelper sem usar o start eu não consigo recuperar o valor!

Comment: Usar print_r($this->Session->read()) não resolve seu caso, pois ele lê somente as seções do Cake. Já tentou a global no model?

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona também ele me retorna `Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: Post um trecho do código pra ficar mais claro o que está fazendo. Eu uso $_SESSION em alguns casos e nunca tive problema. Você já tentou remover o session_start()? O Cake inicializa a sessão sozinho.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e postei o código utilizado!

Comment: Criei um gist com o código que vai te atender. Veja aqui: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd7b2025df22d6b28489

Comment: Consegui aqui, esqueci de desabilitar o debug no `core.php`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27729/discussion-between-danilo-miguel-and-acomerlatto).

Comment: Desculpa a demora, poderias abrir o chat novamente?